# Iteration through hex string

Tags: python, hex

I have such binary string:

```
 some_bytes = b'Q\x00\xfdM\xf6\x02\x14M\x03'
```

I would like to iterate through elements of this string (do not have to print, may be do some action with `x`):

```
 for x in some_bytes:
     print (x, end=' ')
```

The code above print `81 0 253 77 246 2 20 77 3`,

but I want to see `\Q \x00 \xfd M \xf6 \x02 \x14 M \x03`

How can I do it? I can not do `chr()`, because it raises `UnicodeEncodeError` for `\xfd`.

Comment: Why do you need the string representation? Those numbers are the bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for x in some_bytes:
...     print('{!r}'.format(bytes([x]))[2:-1], end=' ')
...     
...     
Q \x00 \xfd M \xf6 \x02 \x14 M \x03
```